# Is there a better way to intelligently sort dates?

Tags: javascript, sorting, date

I have an array of dates, that looks something along these lines:

```
var dates = [
  { day: 14, month: 4 },
  { day: 28, month: 4 },
  { day: 29, month: 11 },
  { day: 2, month: 9 }
];
```

And I want to sort them, from the perspective that now it's August. I mean, 11th month is closer than the 4th month. I have thought about it a lot, and finally came up with [this solution.](http://jsbin.com/hanem/1/edit?js,output)
First of all, it doesn't really work, because of problems with concatenating JSON arrays, but that's a minor issue. 
 I think this is a pretty bad way to do this, in terms of efficiency or something. Can you come up with anything better? Thanks!

Comment: why not use the date object? Or search stackoverflow for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check this [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/federuci/1/edit). The main idea is get the current month and offset each month in the array by the current month. Then if a result is negative, which means it is a month after the current one, i try to figure out what is its sequence.

The code changed is the following:

```
Dates.prototype.sort = function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var currentMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
  for(var j = 0; j < this.arr.length - 1; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.arr.length - 1; i++) {
      var month = this.arr[i].month - currentMonth;
      var nextMonth = this.arr[i + 1].month - currentMonth;
      if(month < 0){
        month = 12 + month;
      }
      if(nextMonth < 0){
        nextMonth = 12 + nextMonth;
      }
      if (month > nextMonth) 
        this.switch(i, i + 1); 

      else if (month == nextMonth)
        if (this.arr[i].day > this.arr[i + 1].day)
          this.switch(i , i + 1);

    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not modify the array or any prototype. It's just a matter of building a date object when comparing each element.

```
var today = new Date(),
current_day = today.getDate(),
current_month = today.getMonth() + 1,
current_year = today.getFullYear(),
comparator = function(d1, d2) {
    var y1, y2, date1, date2;
    if (d1.month > current_month || (d1.month == current_month && d1.day > current_day)) {
        y1 = current_year;
    } else {
        y1 = current_year + 1;
    }
    if (d2.month > current_month || (d2.month == current_month && d2.day > current_day)) {
        y2 = current_year;
    } else {
        y2 = current_year + 1;
    }
    date1 = new Date(y1, d1.month - 1, d1.day);
    date2 = new Date(y2, d2.month - 1, d2.day);
    return date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
};
dates.sort(comparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

sorting on distance to current month of month property can be done using:

```
Dates.prototype.sort = function() {
  var m = new Date().getMonth()+1
     ,tmparr = this.arr.slice().map( function(v) {
                  v.distance = Math.abs(+v.month - m); return v;
              })
  ;

  this.arr = tmparr.sort( function(a,b) { return a.distance - b.distance; } )
                   .map( function(v) { delete v.distance; return v; } );
};
```

See the adjusted [**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/fehadasa/2/edit?js,output)